# Why this integral diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

For $D=[0,+\infty)×[0,+\infty)$ and $f(x,y)=(1+x+y)^{-1}$, why does the integral over $D$ of $f(x,y)$ not converge?

It's not like $\rho/(1+\rho|\sin\theta+\cos\theta|)$ which to infinite is like $1/(|\sin\theta+\cos\theta|)$ and, close to $0$ is like $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

$$D'=[0,+\infty)\times [0,1]$$

and note that

$$\int_D \frac1{1+x+y} \,dx\,dy \ge \int_{D'} \frac1{1+x+y} \,dx\,dy\ge \int_{D'} \frac1{2+x} \, dx \, dy$$

Comment: This is equivalent to put myself on the curve $\gamma(t)=(t,1)$ and showing that for $t->0$ the integral explode, right?

Comment: @OsvaldoPaniccia Since f(x,y,) is positive, the given integral is $\ge$ of the integral of f(x,y) calculated on D' which is $\geq$  of the integral of f(x,1) calculated on D' (since $y_{max}=1$ in D').

Answer (score 2):

First, we see that $f$ is positive on all of $D$. This means that we can consider a smaller region, and if it diverges there it still diverges on ll of $D$. Consider the region $E\subseteq D$ given by $E = [0,\infty)\times [0,1]$. On $E$, we have $f(x, y)\geq \frac{1}{2+x}$, and we have
$$
\iint_Df(x, y)\,dx\,dy \geq \iint_Ef(x, y)\,dx\,dy = \int_0^\infty \int_0^1f(x, y)\,dy\,dx\\
\geq \int_0^\infty\int_0^1\frac{1}{2+x}dy\,dx = \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2+x}dx
$$
which diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the area of the domain grows like $xy$, while the integrand decreases like $\dfrac1{1+x+y}$, which is insufficient to compensate.